# Нужно вырезать выбранные файлы через TreeView в winform приложении под C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Собственно реализовано уже удаление любых выбранных файлов через TreeView, а также их копирование (включая папки), но а нужно ещё как-то функцию вырезать прикрутить чтобы данные при удалении оставались в буфере. Каким способом можно реализовать функцию вырезать когда известно уже какие узлы TreeView выделены?

```
  //вырезать
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //сначала копируем в буффер а потом удаляем из того места где брали
        StringCollection paths = new StringCollection();
        Copy_Files("", tv1.Nodes, paths);
        if (paths.Count > 0)
        {
            Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
            RemoveSelectedNodes("", tv1.Nodes); //удаление после того как копировали
            MessageBox.Show("Выбранные данные вырезаны");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Должен быть выбран хотя бы один элемент!");
        }
    }

    public void RemoveSelectedNodes(string pt,TreeNodeCollection nodes)// delete selected nodes from memory
    {
        List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Checked)
            {
                checkedNodes.Add(node);
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveSelectedNodes(pt + "\\" + node.Text,node.Nodes);
            }
        }

        foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes)
        {
            nodes.Remove(checkedNode);
            string[] paths = new string[checkedNodes.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    paths[i] = (root + pt + "\\" + checkedNode.Text);
                    if (File.Exists(paths[i])) //это файл
                    {
                        File.Delete(paths[i]);
                    }
                    else //это директория
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(paths[i],true);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Должен быть выбран хотя бы один элемент!");
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //копирование выделенных файлов в буфер
    private void Copy_Files(string pt,TreeNodeCollection nodes, StringCollection paths)
    {
        List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Checked)
            {
                checkedNodes.Add(node);
            }
            else
            {
               Copy_Files(pt + "\\" + node.Text,node.Nodes,paths);
            }
        }

        foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes)
        {
            paths.Add(root  + pt + "\\" + checkedNode.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: функция "вырезать" - это "копировать" и "удалить", причем строго в этом порядке. Если у вас уже реализованы копирование и удаление, просто примените их последовательно к одному и тому же набору файлов. Либо используйте команду [File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ну собственно у меня в таком порядке и идет: Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
RemoveSelectedNodes("", tv1.Nodes);

Comment: Или Clipboard надо как-то по другому тут использовать...

Comment: чтобы детально ответить,  надо видеть как у вас это реализовано. Я честно говоря не очень понимаю зачем вам вообще Clipboard. Все можно сделать родными средствами .NET, которые являются оболочкой над WinAPI.

Comment: Добавил кнопку по которой происходит сие действие.

Comment: А где копирование? Удаление вижу, копирование в буфер вижу, а само копирование не вижу. Без него и не должно работать

Comment: Т.е. мы должны в начале данные скопировать куда-то кроме буфера?

Comment: Естественно. Вы же не сами файлы в буфер кладете, а только пути к ним. Так что сначала копируем, потом удаляем.

Comment: Ну таким образом тогда да получится )) просто думал можно как-то без такого копирования обойтись...

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение)

Comment: Без копирования я в первом комментарии написал - `File.Move` и тоже для папок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже отдельный файл может превышать размер ОЗУ в разы. Поэтому применительно к объектам файловой системы команда "вырезать" не удаляет файлы сразу, а только запоминает список вырезаемых файлов до момента вставки. Удаление происходит только после вызова команды "Вставить" и копирования файлов и папок в новое расположение. Если вставка не вызывается, то файлы остаются на старом месте. Если в процессе копирования происходит ошибка - операция прерывается и файлы, которые еще не были полностью(!) скопированы остаются на старом месте. Менять подобный порядок действий опасно и не нужно, можете просто потерять файлы (я знаю что их можно восстановить, но это отдельный <strike>геморрой</strike> непростой вопрос).

Таким образом, в приведенном вами коде присутствует копирование путей и удаление содержимого файлов, а копирование содержимого отсутствует. Следовательно ваша реализация операции "вырезать" просто удаляет файлы и сохраняет пути к несуществующим файлам.

Варианты решения:

- Добавить копирование содержимого в новое расположение.
- Использовать вместо удаления команды `File.Move` и `Directory.Move`
- Использовать оригинальный подход к данной операции, а именно: помечаем (например цветом) файлы и папки как вырезанные, запоминаем пути в буфере, если следующая команда "Вставить" - перемещаем выделенные объекты, иначе снимаем пометку с выделенных объектов.

Comment: Насчет File.move и Directory.move действительно заменяет удаление)